# Web Api 2 deserialize LINQ2SQL object with collection property

Tags: ajax, json, serialization, asp.net-web-api2

The context is long, so I'll start with the question: *Why isn't the InductionQAs collection property being rehydrated?*

In a Web API 2 method, LINQ produces an object `ic` with a collection property `InductionQAs`. After I eliminate a huge irrelevant object graph and prevent a circular reference, `ic` is returned by the method. Here's the code. Error handling has been removed for brevity.

```
// GET: api/InductionContent/5
[Authorize]
public object Get(int id)
{
  var dc = new Models.InductionsDataContext();
  var user = GetUser(dc);
  var ic = dc.InductionContents.Single(c => c.InductionContentID == id);
  ic.User.InductionContents.Clear(); //don't ship this it can be huge
  return ic;
}
```

Here's the invoking JS code. Ignore the authorisation header business, that all works fine.

```
var token, headers;
$.ajax({ //get session token
  url: "api/token",
  headers: { Authorization: "Basic " + btoa("username:password") },
}).done(function (result) {
  localStorage.setItem('access_token', token = result.access_token);
  var headers = { Authorization: "Session " + token };
  $.ajax({ //get an induction content object 
    url: "api/InductionContent/5",
    headers: headers
  }).done(function (ic) {
    //at this point we have an object graph
    var json = JSON.stringify(ic);
  });
});
```

This is what JSON.stringify(ic) returns:

```
{
    "InductionContentID": 5,
    "InductionTemplateID": 1,
    "InductionContent1": "<p>We recognise that it is ...(redacted)</p>",
    "InductionContentOrder": 301,
    "Caption": "Workplace Health and Safety",
    "OwnerId": 0,
    "ParentId": 0,
    "TopicId": 5,
    "InductionQAs": [
        {
            "InductionQAID": 1,
            "InductionContentID": 5,
            "Question": "Who is responsible for ...(redacted)",
            "Answers": "A|B|C|*D",
            "InductionQAOrder": 1
        }
    ],
    "User": null
}
```

All well and good. Now we round-trip it.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "post",
  url: "api/InductionContent",
  headers: headers,
  data: ic
});
```

This calls into the following web method:

```
// POST: api/InductionContent
[Authorize]
public void Post([FromBody]Models.InductionContent ic)
{
  //redacted
}
```

The method is invoked and `ic` has a value. `ic.User` contains data, but inspection of `ic.InductionQAs` reveals that it has not been initialised.

Serialisation is configured as follows:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
  GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
  GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings
    .ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
  GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers
    .Add(new AuthenticationHandler(CreateConfiguration()));
  FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
  RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
  BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MVC is smart but not quite smart enough. It needs a hint. The "round-trip" call *should* have looked like this:

```
    $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: "api/InductionContent",
      contentType: "text/json",
      headers: headers,
      data: JSON.stringify(ic)
    }).done(function (result) {
      //etc
    });
```

There are two things to note here.

- We have assumed manual control of payload encoding
- We have annotated the post with the encoding used

### One another thing...

Having got it all to work I decided the method should return the id of the freshly minted database row. Changing the method return type to `int` and appending a last line

```
return nc.InductionContentId;
```

should have been enough, but the done method of the ajax call totally failed to fire. Investigation with Fiddler revealed that the id value had indeed been returned **with a content-type of text/json**.

When you specify a content type for a jQuery ajax call, the same content type is used for the response. If the return value is an object, this will work fine. The object will be serialised as JSON and at the other end it will be parsed to provide the result object.

But for a simple value like an int, this comes unglued at the parsing stage. To resolve the problem, a return content type of plain text by using the dataType attribute.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "post",
  url: "api/InductionContent",
  contentType: "text/json",
  dataType: "text",
  headers: headers,
  data: JSON.stringify(ic)
}).done(function (result) {
  var id = result;
  //etc
});
```